# ruby/caxlsx: how to define different surrounding cell's borders styles?

Tags: excel, ruby, rubygems, border, axlsx

I cannot find a way to have different borders on a cell with the excellent caxlsx gem on ruby.
From the doc, the expected style for borders is defined using (for instance):

```
{style: :thick, color: 'FF0000', edges:[:left,:right]}
```

So, it seems imposible to have a red thick border on the left, and a blue dash border on the right for instance.
Am i wrong?

Comment: I found this in the source code, but haven't managed to get it to work...

https://github.com/caxlsx/caxlsx/blob/master/lib/axlsx/stylesheet/border_pr.rb

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the game, but maybe someone else will stumble over the same issue.

When you use edges, you can't mix the styles.
However, you can pass in border_left, border_top and so on.
So something like this works:

```rb
    sheet["A1:A1"].each do |cell|
      cell.style = styles.add_style(
        border_right: { style: :medium, color: '000000' },
        border_bottom: { style: :thin, color: '000000' }
      )
    end
```

```rb
style = workbook.styles.add_style(
  border: { style: :none, color: nil },
  border_top: { style: :double, color: '0000FF' },
  border_right: { style: :thick, color: 'FF0000' },
  border_bottom: { style: :double, color: '0000FF' },
  border_left: { style: :thick, color: 'FF0000' }
)
```

source: https://github.com/axlsx-styler-gem/axlsx_styler/issues/31#issuecomment-943905188